# Solr Admin UI: meaning of "current" field in core statistics

Tags: solr

What is the meaning of "Current" field in Apache Solr Admin UI in the core overview statistics? I can't seem to find anything about it in the [relevant docs page](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/core-specific-tools.html). I am using version 7.4.

[image: Solr Admin UI core overview statistics]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"current" means that there is pending documents that [haven't been committed yet](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-Admin-core-status-Index-is-not-Current-tp4130493p4130687.html). Issue a commit or optimize and the state should change.

From [the Lucene docs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/7_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#isCurrent--):

> Check whether any new changes have occurred to the index since this reader was opened.
>
> If this reader was created by calling open(org.apache.lucene.store.Directory), then this method checks if any further commits (see IndexWriter.commit()) have occurred in the directory.
>
> If instead this reader is a near real-time reader (ie, obtained by a call to open(IndexWriter), or by calling openIfChanged(org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader) on a near real-time reader), then this method checks if either a new commit has occurred, or any new uncommitted changes have taken place via the writer. Note that even if the writer has only performed merging, this method will still return false.
>
> In any event, if this returns false, you should call openIfChanged(org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader) to get a new reader that sees the changes.